# Do Synthea names generally end with a number

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I'm using data from synthea and it looks like most (all?) of the given and family names I'm getting back end with a three digit number (e.g. Gregg522).  Is this part of the design of synthea or am I parsing the data incorrectly.  A snippet of the json I'm getting back is shown below.  If this is part of the design, what is the motivation of ending the name with a number (I would think this would make the data less realistic).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they generally do. It is sometimes nice to be able to see that the patients are fake/synthetic ones. However, this is a setting you can change: In the synthea.properties file, look for the setting "append_numbers_to_person_names" and set it to false.